# dbt post hook relation "my_table" does not exist

Tags: dbt

I am building some models using dbt.

I have a model so -

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(
    col1, col2
  ) AS col,
  ....
FROM
  {{ source(
    'db',
    'tbl'
  ) }}
  WHERE ....
```

This model has a config section calling a macro

```
{{- config(
  post_hook = [macro()],
  materialized='table'
) -}}
```

Within the macro I use `{% if execute %}` and I also log to check the execute value `{{ log('Calling update macro with exec value = ' ~ execute) }}`

When I run `dbt compile` I do not expect the macro to fire according to the [documentation](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/execute). However, it does and actually sets the execute to true triggering the update and causing on error as the table doesn't exist. Am I missing something or is this a dbt bug? I am confused!

Here's the line from the logs -
`2021-09-15 20:48:16.864555 (Thread-1): Calling update macro with exec value = True`

.. and the error is
 `relation "schema.my_table" does not exist`

Appreciate any pointers someone might have, thanks

Comment: 1. is the model file referenced above above actually called `my_table`? so you should be able to reproduce the error with `dbt compile -m my_table` right?
2. is there a reason you're not passing [`{{ this }}`](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/this) as an argument to your macro?

Comment: Hello @AndersSwanson - thanks for your response.
I do not pass `{{ this }}` as I can access it without explicitly passing it in. 
I got the error from the log and that points me to the post hook macro where I am updating the model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so here's what I found out about dbt.

When you `dbt compile` or `dbt run` the first time, the tables do not exist in the database yet. However, **both** compile and run will check the db objects exist and throw an error otherwise. So, my select within the macro failed irrespective of me using `{% if execute %}`

I called the `adapter.get_relation()` to check if the table exists -

```
{%- set source_relation = adapter.get_relation(
        database=this.database ,
        schema=this.schema,
        identifier=this.name) -%}
```

and used the check condition -

```
{% set table_exists=source_relation is not none  %}
```

For an incremental run, the fix was easier -

```
{% if execute and is_incremental() %}
```

Now, my code is fixed :)

Comment: thanks for following up and sharing what you learned! not to harp on the same point, but I wonder if using `{{ this }}` is required to exist at compile time. might be worth checking out and would obviate the need for your `is not none` check?

Comment: @AndersSwanson- No problem! Jjust tried that and still no luck!
There's more I learnt from the issue. My assumption was `post_hook` ran after the model. This to my surprise isn't quite true. If building the model first time, and `post-hook` calls a macro that refers to the model (in my case to get and insert the `max(created_date)` into another table) no insert happens in the first run although the run complete without error. Only subsequent runs insert records since by then the table physically exists.
Always something to learn :)

Comment: have you looked at how the `table` materialization works? def worth checking out. you can see that's hooks are part of the "model creation" like you said. https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt/blob/develop/core/dbt/include/global_project/macros/materializations/table/table.sql

Comment: Thank you for sharing the GitHub link @AndersSwanson. The commit happens after `post_hook` and that explains everything to me!